# Serializer remove parent field django

Tags: django, django-serializer

```
   {
    "episode": {
        "id": 6,
        "channel_id": 2,
        "channel": {
            "id": 2,
            "tags": [
                "new"
            ]
    },
   {
    "episode": {
        "id": 7,
        "channel_id": 3,
        "channel": {
            "id": 2,
            "tags": [
                "new"
            ]
    }
},
```

Hey I am new to Django. I am wondering how to remove episode parent written in the serializer response and directly go into the id, channel.  Episode is not useful for me here. I have a model that sets the priority of these episodes. Have excluded the priority and id field but don't know how to remove episode parent.

```
class TrendingEpisode(models.Model):
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

class Episode(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(EpisodeTag)
    #some other fields
```

Comment: please show your models

Comment: updated. Please check @seuling

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `TrendingEpisode` with foreignkey? Just use `Episode` only.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(EpisodeTag)
    #some other fields
```

Then you can get your serialized data like below

`{
        "id": 6,
        "channel_id": 2,
        "channel": {
            "id": 2,
            "tags": [
                "new"
            ]
        },
    }`

Comment: because I manually want to set some episodes as trending and have priority in them. For easily entering the details . Creating a new model solves the problem